Time dilation effect for astronauts travelling to Alpha Centauri Sol in a spaceship at $0.87c$ the speed of light?
Does this mean also that if we want to sent astronauts to Alpha Centauri solar system, 4lys away with the spaceship accelerating to $0.87c$ speed of light (i.e. Lorentz factor γ=2), then the spaceship will arrive at approximately 4.6 years (i.e. 4 years and 7 months) in Earth time but actually for the astronauts inside the ship it will take only half this time thus 2 years and 3.5 months in Earth time?

The elapsed time (both for the astronauts inside the space ship and for observers on Earth) will depend on how quickly the ship accelerates and whether it also decelerates at its destination.

Kinetic time dilation is only related to speed.  So the acceleration does not matter except for the speed that the ship is traveling at each point in the acceleration process.  Otherwise, if acceleration was the key factor, a high powered bullet would have very significant time dilation while it is accelerating in the barrel of the rifle.  This does not happen.

You can simplify your thought experiment by assuming the spaceship passes Earth already travelling at 0.87c, in which case the time that passes on the ship during its journey to the star will be 2.3 years.
The effect is symmetrical. If there is a second spaceship trailing the first at a distance of four light years, then the time that passes on Earth between the first spaceship passing and the second will be 2.3 years. According to the clocks on the spaceships the interval will be 4.6 years, so the Earth will be time dilated in the frame of the ships by a factor of two.
